# Bibtex reference numbering error

Tags: bibtex

I have a bibtex file as below:

```
@article{hong,
      author         = "JR. Maze  and PL. Stanwix and JS. Hodges and S Hong and JM Taylor  and P Cappellaro and L. Jiang  and MV Dutt and E Togan  and AS. Zibrov and A. Yacoby  and RL. Walsworth  and MD. Lukin",
      title          = "{Nanoscale magnetic sensing with an individual electronic spin in diamond}",
      journal        = "Nature",
      volume         = "455",
      year           = "2008",
      number         = "7213",
      pages          = "644-647",
      doi            = "10.1038/nature07279",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",
}

@article{qian,
      author         = "D Bera  and L Qian  and TK Tseng  and PH Holloway ",
      title          = "{ Quantum Dots and Their Multimodal Applications: A Review}",
      journal        = "Materials (Basel)",
      volume         = "3",
      year           = "2010",
      number         = "4",
      doi            = "10.3390/ma3042260",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}



@article{kj,
      author         = "Kjaergaard, M. and Schwartz, M. E. and Braumuller, J. and Krantz, P. and Wang J. and Gustavsson S. and Oliver D. W. ",
      title          = "{ Superconducting Qubits: Current State of Play}",
      journal        = "Annual Review of Condensed Matter Physics",
      volume         = "11",
      year           = "2019",
      pages         = "369-395",
      doi            = "10.1146/annurev-conmatphys-031119-050605",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}

@article{schir,
      author         = "R Schirhagl  and K Chang  and M Loretz  and CLL Degen",
      title          = "{Nitrogen-Vacancy Centers in Diamond: Nanoscale Sensors for Physics and Biology}",
      journal        = "Annual Review of Physical Chemistry",
      volume         = "65",
      year           = "2014",
      pages        ="83-105",
      doi            = "10.1146/annurev-physchem-040513-103659",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}

@article{brz,
      author         = "CD Bruzewics and John Chiaverini  and R McConnell  and J.M. Sage  ",
      title          = "{Trapped-ion quantum computing: Progress and challenges}",
      journal        = "Applied Physics Reviews",
      volume         = "6",
      year           = "2019",
      number         = "021314",
      doi            = "10.1063/1.5088164",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}



@article{div,
      author         = "D Davalos and M Ziman and C pineda. ",
      title          = "{Divisibility of qubit channels and dynamical maps}",
      journal        = "Quantum",
      volume         = "3",
      year           = "2019",
      pages         = "144",
      doi            = "10.22331/q-2019-05-20-144",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{blp,
      author         = "HP Breuer and EL Laine and J Piilo",
      title          = "{Measure for the Degree of Non-Markovianity of Quantum Processes in Open Systems}",
      journal        = "Physical Review Letters",
      volume         = "103",
      year           = "2009",
      doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.210401",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}




@article{ndiv,
      author         = "S. C. Hou and  X. X. Yi and S. X. Yu and C. H. Oh",
      title          = "{An alternative non-Markovianity measure by divisibility of dynamical map}",
      journal        = "Phys. Rev. A",
      volume         = "83",
      number="062115 ",
      year           = "2011",
      doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevA.83.062115",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{geo,
      author         = "S. Lorenzo and F. Plastina and M. Paternostro",
      title          = "{Geometrical characterization of non-Markovianity}",
      journal        = "Phys. Rev. A",
      volume         = "88",
      number="020102 ",
      year           = "2013",
      doi            = "    10.1103/PhysRevA.88.020102",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}

@book{oqs,
  title={The Theory of Open Quantum Systems},
  author={HP Breuer  and F Petruccione },
  isbn={0198520638},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}


@article{2016,
      author         = "HP Breuer",
      title          = "{Colloquium: Non-Markovian dynamics in open quantum systems}",
      journal        = "REVIEWS OF MODERN PHYSICS",
      volume         = "88",
      year           = "2016",
      doi            = "10.1103/RevModPhys.88.021002",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{gksl,
      author         = "V Gorini and A Kossakowski",
      title          = "{Completely positive dynamical semigroups of N‐level systems}",
      journal        = "Journal of Mathematical Physics.",
      volume         = "17",
      year           = "1976",
      doi            = "    10.1063/1.522979",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{brown,
      author         = "F. Intravaia and S. Maniscalco and A. Messina",
      title          = "{Density-matrix operatorial solution of the non-Markovian master equation for quantum Brownian motion
}",
      journal        = "American Physical Society",
      volume         = "67",
      year           = "2003",
      doi            = "/10.1103/PhysRevA.67.042108",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}



@article{jay,
      author         = "B. J. Dalton and Stephen M. Barnett and B. M. Garraway",
      title          = "{Theory of pseudomodes in quantum optical processes}",
      journal        = "American Physical Society",
      volume         = "64",
      year           = "2001",
      doi            = "https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.64.053813",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc"}

@article{arrow,
      author         = "J. Goold and M. Huber and A. Riera and L. d. Rio and P. Skrzypczyk",
      title          = "{The role of quantum information in thermodynamics --- a topical review}",
      journal        = "J. Phys. A: Math. Theor.",
      volume         = "49",
      year           = "2016",
      doi            = "    10.1088/1751-8113/49/14/143001",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{cry,
      author         = "C.A. Fuchs and J. van de Graaf",
      title          = "{Cryptographic distinguishability measures for quantum-mechanical states}",
      journal        = "IEEE Transactions on Information Theory.",
      volume         = "45",
      year           = "1999",
      doi            = "    10.1109/18.761271",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{rus,
      author         = "MB Ruskai",
      title          = "{Beyond Strong Subadditivity? Improved Bounds on the Contraction of Generalised Relative Entropy
}",
      journal        = "Journal of Mathematical Physics.",
      volume         = "6",
      year           = "1994",
      doi            = "    10.1142/S0129055X94000407",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{wis,
      author         = "Steffen Wißmann and Antti Karlsson and Elsi-Mari Laine and Jyrki Piilo and Heinz-Peter Breuer
",
      title          = "{Optimal state pairs for non-Markovian quantum dynamics

}",
      journal        = "Physics Review A",
      volume         = "86",
      year           = "2012",
      doi            = "    10.1103/PhysRevA.86.062108",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{apo,
      author         = "Tony J. G. Apollaro and Carlo Di Franco and Francesco Plastina and Mauro Paternostro
",
      title          = "{Memory-keeping effects and forgetfulness in the dynamics of a qubit coupled to a spin chain

}",
      journal        = "Phys Rev A",
      volume         = "83",
      year           = "2011",
      doi            = "    10.1103/PhysRevA.83.032103",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}

@article{bose,
      author         = "S Bose
",
      title          = "{Quantum Communication through an Unmodulated Spin Chain

}",
      journal        = "Physical Review Letters",
      volume         = "91",
      year           = "2003",
      doi            = "    10.1103/PhysRevLett.91.207901",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}

@article{prop,
      author         = "Z. Y. Xu and W. L. Yang and M. Feng
",
      title          = "{Proposed method for direct measurement of non-Markovian character of the qubits
coupled to bosonic reservoirs

}",
      journal        = "Phys. Rev. A ",
      volume         = "81",
      year           = "2010",
      doi            = "    10.1103/PhysRevA.81.044105",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}

@article{bello,
      author         = "B. Bellomo and R. Lo Franco and G. Compagno
",
      title          = "{Non-Markovian Effects on the Dynamics of Entanglement

}",
      journal        = "Physica; Review Letters",
      volume         = "99",
      year           = "2007",
      doi            = "    10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.160502",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{comp,
      author         = "Carole Addis and Bogna Bylicka and Dariusz Chruscinski and Sabrina Maniscalco
",
      title          = "{Comparative study of non-Markovianity measures in exactly solvable one and two
qubit models.}",
      journal        = "Phys. Rev. A",
      volume         = "90",
      year           = "2014",
      doi            = "    10.1103/PhysRevA.90.052103",
      primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}


@article{2qbitbloch,
doi = {10.1088/0305-4470/34/47/324},
    year = 2001,
    volume = {34},
    number = {47},
    pages = {10243-10252},
    author = {R{\'{e}}my Mosseri and Rossen Dandoloff},
    title = {Geometry of entangled states, Bloch spheres and Hopf fibrations},
    journal = {Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General},
  primaryClass   = "gr-qc",}



@book{chuang,
  title={Quantum Coomputation and Quantum Information},
  author={I. Chuang  and M. Nielsen },
  isbn={9781107002173},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},}
```

Unfortunately when I put this in my miktex, the in-text citation for some reason starts are not ordered correspondingly, leading to the references being wrong. For example although hong is cited first it appears as [2] in the text. Meanwhile
although comp is cited last it appears second in the list.

I am using `\bibliomatter \bibilographystyle{vancouver}`

Comment: Welcome to  TeX.SE.

Comment: How or where is `\bibliomatter` defined?

Comment: \bibliomatter is not really needed, I just put in \bibliography{ref.bib}. It does not matter whether I put in \bibliomatter.

Comment: Also I keep getting the error that the name of the citation is undefined for some reason even though they are correctly spelt in the text.

Comment: Did you perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: Hint: if you happen to know that a command -- say, `\bibliomatter` -- is irrelevant, it's a good idea not to mention it in your query.

Comment: I forgot that it does not make any difference

Comment: Could I upload the packages used somewhere I have a very extensive package.

Comment: Please answer my earlier question: Did you perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: Yes, I have done so.

Comment: I think it is due to how the bibtex entries are written somehow when I put the firs reference as \cite{apo} it does indeed work as intended.